# Pandas Dataframe from csv not displaying correctly

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to import a csv file (25MB - 80000 rows)  into pandas dataframe but it's not displaying correctly. The columns are seperated with a ';' when calling `df.columns`.

```
  Originated GeoZone;Booking ...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
1  PARIS;PARIS;;MARKer;EQDff;...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
2  PARIS;PARIS;;MARKer;EQDff;...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
3  PARIS;PARIS;;MARKer;EQDff;...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
4  PARIS;PARIS;;MARKer;EQDff;...
```

The csv file is perfectly clear on Excel. Why is it not well interpreted by pandas.

Comment: Could you share what all you've tried?

Comment: Can you try: `pd.read_csv('your df', sep = ';')` ?

Comment: clearly your delimiter is `;`. `read_csv` default is `:`

Comment: CSV literally means "comma separated values".  How various programs from python to excel parse non-comma separators tends to vary.  General solution is to specify the separator explicitly, as @Junkrat does above

Comment: @Junkrat yes that works!

Comment: You can accept any one of the answers below then :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [delimiter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html?highlight=csv#pandas.read_csv) or `sep` attribute in `read_csv`:

> `sep : str, default ‘,’`
>
> Delimiter to use. If sep is None, the C engine cannot automatically detect the separator, but the Python parsing engine can, meaning the latter will be used and automatically detect the separator by Python’s builtin sniffer tool, csv.Sniffer. In addition, separators longer than 1 character and different from '\s+' will be interpreted as regular expressions and will also force the use of the Python parsing engine. Note that regex delimiters are prone to ignoring quoted data. Regex example: '\r\t'.
>
> `delimiter : str, default None`
>
> Alias for sep.

`df = pd.read_csv('waka.csv', sep=';')`

Answer (score 3):

This problem might be caused by different separator in Excel, it depends usually on country you are from.

You can try this:

```
pd.read_csv("your file", sep = ";")
```

This should works.

Theory: this is caused by different separators for csv files. Python use comma by default, but some files might use something other the comma, for example: ";" or "|".

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

```
pd.read_csv('your file', sep = ';')
```

As @RafaelC pointed out, your default delimiter is `;`, so you have to specify it separately